mvp for the start up
We need expert technical guidance for our MVP model to ensure we focus on the essentials. It's crucial that we don't overlook any critical features or, conversely, overcomplicate the product by adding too much. Our primary goal is to validate our idea efficiently and effectively. If possible, we'd like advice on the best practices for selecting the tech stack, structuring development phases, and implementing scalable but minimalistic solutions. We'd also appreciate a review of our current plan to identify any potential pitfalls or oversights.

Stack Overflow is for specific programming problems, not general advice. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask].
